# $this->find('all', array(...))

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, conditional-statements

I know how find-all works and I wrote a search query which will search an expression in different columns of a datatable. all works well.

But now, I want to search for the expression not only in a flat data-array, I want to search in a child-array. I have the following structure:

```
[Company] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [user_id] => 3
                [name] => TEAM-Security
                [address1] => Dorfstrasse 9
            )
 [Service] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [cat] => Reinigung
                        [name] => Baureinigung
                        [created] => 2014-07-13 00:00:00
                        [modified] => 2014-07-13 00:00:00
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [cat] => Reinigung
                        [name] => Wohnungsreinigung
                        [created] => 2014-07-13 00:00:00
                        [modified] => 2014-07-13 00:00:00
                    )
            )
```

Now, I am able to search in the different "Company-columns". Now, I want to search also in the columns of the Service-childs. I read a lot of blogs, webpages etc., but I couldn't find any hints how to work that out.

My simple solution so far:

```
$searchterm = 'TEAM';
$pending = $this->Company->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Company.name like' => '%$searchterm%')
));
```

The troubles I have, I want to search now in a child with subarrays. I want to search for **"Baureinigung"** etc. Do I have to do a 'foreach' or something manually? Or is there a cake-way which I don't know so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the biggest pains for me in working with Cake - trying to search on deeper columns and use anything other than LEFT joins.  Here is what's worked for me.  I'm assuming that you are working in the Company Model - if not, you should be. This can be slightly modified to work in the Controller, but it belongs in the Model.  I'm also assuming that your HABTM is using a join table called `companies_services`

First unbind the current associations to the table you want to inner join for the query:

```
$this->unbindModel(array('hasAndBelongsToMany' => array('Service')));
```

Then you need to explicitly join up your tables using INNER joins.  To do this in CakePHP 2.x, you use the join key in the options argument of the find method:

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'companies_services',
            'alias' => 'CompanyServices',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'CompanyServices.company_id = Company.id'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'services',
            'alias' => 'Service',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Service.id = CompanyServices.id',
                'Service.name LIKE ' => '%' . $service_search_term . '%'
            )
        ),
     ),
     'conditions' => array('Company.name LIKE ' => '%'. $company_search_term . '%',
     'recursive' => -1
));
```

One other thing I'll note is that I have run into situations where I had to explicitly declare the fields that I wanted returned after doing this. To do so you would add a 'fields' key to the options array above, so for instance (following on from the 'recursive' line above):

```
...
'recursive' => -1,
'fields' => array(
    'Company.id',
    'Company.name',
    'CompanyServices.company_id',
    'CompanyServices.service_id',
    'Service.id',
    'Service.name'
)
....
```

Comment: I like the join-solution, but the data comes not in a cakephp manner. It comes like Company1/Service1, Company1/Service2, Company1/Service3, Company2/Service3, Company4/Service1, Company4/Service6.
I want to have Company1/Service1/Service2/Service3, Company2/Service2, Company4/Service1/Service6

Comment: Now, I implemented this solution. It's not exactly what I want. But it works for now. I grouped by company.id, so I got each company only once. Unfortunately I loose all the other services of this company (which were not searched for). But I can do a workaround. The search functionality is more important in this case. Thanks a lot to everybody. I learned a lot about containable -> for what this is not to use. It goes to sql, but it's more to display information not do searching...

Comment: @cleverketchup The existing relationship between the tables is a LEFT join, and in my experience if you don't unbind that relationship before creating the new INNER join, cake will generate bad SQL resulting an error

Comment: @user1970565 usualy recursive set as-1 is more than enought. Well, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the containable behavior to do some searches on associated data.  Example:

```
  $this->find(
      'all', 
      array(
         'conditions' => array('Company.name like' => '%$searchterm%'),  
         'contain' => array(
               'Service' => array(
                      'conditions' => array(
                            'Service.name like' => '%$searchterm%'
                      )
                )
           )
      )
  );
```

Be aware though that you have to pay particular attention to join types when doing searches on multiple tables at the same time like this.  By default, model associations behave as a left join.

Comment: I have some problems with that... I think it sould work as you wrote Kai. I have a HABTM relation with the model. Doesn't work, but is that the reason?

Comment: @FishWave Because you need to declare **public $actsAs = array('Containable')** variable in your **Company** model

Comment: It works, but I receive the Companies without any Services too. The Service-Array is there and empty. I don't want the Companies with no Services at all.

Comment: @FishWave As I said, you have to pay particular attention to join types.  I did not know what exactly you were trying to find, so I could not give more details than that, but it sounds like what you're looking for is probably an inner join.  So either change your model relationship to be of join type inner, or do a manual inner join.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Company` Model you have define direct association like

```
class Company extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Company';
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Service' =>
                        array(
                              'fields'   => array('name')
                        )
                  );
}
```

After that you can try following

```
$pending = $this->Company->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array("OR" => array(
              'Company.name like' => '%$searchterm%',
              'Service.name like' => '%$searchterm%'
        )))
);
```

Comment: No, this solution does not work. I have a HABTM within the Model. Cake respectively MySQL says: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Service.name' in 'where clause'

Comment: Read this post may be helpful http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/habtm-does-not-work-with-find-when-I-specify-fields-td1264200.html

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a bit complex and probably not optimized but will work:

```
        $data = $this->Company->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    "OR" => array(
                        'Company.name like' => '%$searchterm%',
                        'Service.name like' => '%$searchterm%'
                    )
                ),
                'contain' => array(
                    'Service' => array(
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'Service.name like' => '%$searchterm%'
                        )
                    )
                ),
                'joins' => array(
                    array(
                        'table' => 'companies_services',
                        'alias' => 'CompanyServices',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'CompanyServices.company_id = Company.id'
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'table' => 'services',
                        'alias' => 'Service',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'Service.id = CompanyServices.id'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

Comment: Yes, that works. But therefore I don't need the containable behavior. The condition with the searchterm only is enough. But as I wrote to the other join solution, the data don't come in a cakephp manner.

Comment: @FishWave, joins is not abble to return data in cakes format. That is why I used contain in this example.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, but the data didn't come in a cakephp manner. But anyway, i skipped the contain and it works with the search functionality, but I don't get all the information with each company. Read my other comment at the solution I ticked green. Thanks cleverketchup!